# Change the root path ASP WebApi

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

My angular project is in the `app` folder, so that I refer to it I have to be addressed to `http://localhost:45485/app`, but I want to remove `app` from this url. I'm trying to do it this way, but it doesn`t work. I dont know what to do, please help me.

**web.config file:**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear/>
    <rule name="app" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}app\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/{R:1}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="index.html as document root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In result I have this problem:

[image]

Comment: While I'm interested in how this can be done (properly), curious as to "why"? For a "web api" application? If this is a front end angular project (only), then it seems "round peg in square hole"....

Comment: @EdSF, I just study it all, and do not understand some moments, but why not? And it seems to me that this is really, so I want to try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not getting the "purpose" of this or the gist of the question so *assuming* you just want your SPA to be the "main" entry point (aka `http://example.com/`), while your Angular assets are all in an `/app` folder then, there's no need to juggle around with rewriting rules, nor affect (the entire) `Asp.Net/MVC/Web Api` application (because of rewrite rules).

Not an Angular "expert" so this is a trivial example for you to improve on:

- Your `ng-app` can sit perfectly well in the "default" ("home" -> "index") `View` of an `ASP.Net MVC/Web Api` application - a "container" if you will. No "re-write" rules needed/necessary for it to be the "index" (first/default page) of your web site.

  `index.cshtml` MVC `View` trivial example using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

  ```
  <div id="foo" ng-app="myNgApp">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
  ```
- your Angular assets can be in `/app` folder

  ```
  /app
    index.html
    page2.html
  ```
- Using ui-router (see link above), it would go something like this

  ```
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
     templateUrl: '/app/index.html' //maps to root -> app -> index.html
   })
   .state('foo', {
     templateUrl: '/app/page2.html' //maps to root -> app -> page2.html
   })
  ```

Note that I'm using the full path ("root relative") in the `templateUrl` to the resources as it maps to your web site/application folder instead of just relative (to `app` subfolder).

Hth.